# How to retrieve next 5 hours data from the table in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLENAME
WHERE 
       text_date < GETDATE()
     AND 
       text_date < DATEADD(MINUTE, 300, GETDATE())
```

Is there something wrong in this?

Comment: select * from TABLENAME where 
text_date >=  GetDate() and 
text_date < dateadd(minute, 300, GetDate()) is edit in your query. if you want data between now and next 5 hour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one -

```
DECLARE @Data DATETIME
SELECT @Data = GETDATE()

SELECT *
FROM TABLENAME
WHERE text_date BETWEEN @Data AND DATEADD(MINUTE, 300, @Data)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
 DECLARE @AddTime DATETIME
  SELECT @AddTime = GETDATE();

 SELECT *
  FROM TABLENAME
 WHERE text_date BETWEEN @AddTime AND DATEADD(HOUR, 5, @AddTime );
```

[Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_dateadd.asp)